# Excel VBA: Index = ZOrderPosition in a Shapes collection?

Tags: excel, vba

Is the Index of a Shape in a Shapes collection of a Worksheet always the same as its ZOrderPosition? (One cannot in principle inquire directly about the Index of a given Shape).

I have verified this is true in a few cases (with up to 3000 Shapes), but I found no documentation on this.

I have traversed the whole collection, inquiring about possible differences between Index and ZOrderPosition:

```
Sub dump_shapes()
' Dump information on all shapes in a Shapes collection
    Dim shc As Shapes
    Set shc = ActiveSheet.Shapes
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In shc
      Dim sh2 As Shape
      Set sh2 = sh2idxzosh_shc(shp)
      Dim zoidx As Long
      ' The second argument is not actually the Index, but since we are traversing the 
      ' whole collection, and Index and ZOrderPosition are at most permutations, we are
      ' covering all of the possible Indexes.
      zoidx = idx2zo_shc(shc, shp.ZOrderPosition)
    Next shp
End Sub
```

The functions used for inquiring are shown below. Since the warning in the MsgBox'es never popped, that means that Index=ZOrderPosition, for the cases evaluated.

```
' Functions between the set of shapes S and the set of natural numbers N.
' O=ZOrderPosition : S -> N  (function exists)
' D=From Index : N -> S  (function exists)
' D^-1=Index : S -> N  (function does not exist)
' f=OoD : N -> N  (can be constructed; this is expected to be only a permutation, 
'  i.e., bijective)
' g=DoO : S -> S  (can be constructed)

Function sh2idxzosh_shc(ByRef sh As Shape) As Shape
    Dim shc As Shapes
    Set shc = sh.Parent.Shapes
    Dim zo As Long
    zo = sh.ZOrderPosition
    Dim sh2 As Shape
    Set sh2 = shc(zo)
    ' g=DoO : S -> S
    ' Test Shape : g(S)=S for all s? If so, g=DoO=I ; D=O^-1 ; D^-1=O. Thus, the Index 
    '  is equal to the ZOrderPosition.
    ' Use ZOrderPosition to test Shape : O(g(s))=O(s) for all s? I.e., OoDoO=O? If so, 
    '  given that O is bijective, OoD=I ; D=O^-1 ; D^-1=O. Thus, the index is equal to 
    '  the ZOrderPosition.
    Dim zo2 As Long
    zo2 = sh2.ZOrderPosition
    If (zo2 <> zo) Then
      MsgBox ("Compound ZOrderPosition: " & zo2 & ", ZOrderPosition: " & zo)
    End If
    Set sh2idxzosh_shc = sh2
    'Set sh2 = Nothing
End Function

Function idx2zo_shc(ByRef shc As Shapes, idx As Long) As Integer
    Dim sh As Shape
    Set sh = shc(idx)
    Dim zo As Long
    zo = sh.ZOrderPosition
    ' f=OoD : N -> N
    ' Test index : f(i)=i for all i? If so, f=OoD=I ; D=O^-1 ; D^-1=O. Thus, the Index is 
    '  equal to the ZOrderPosition.
    If (zo <> idx) Then
      MsgBox ("Index: " & idx & ", ZOrderPosition: " & zo)
    End If
    idx2zo_shc = zo
End Function
```

PS: I have adapted the functions for the ChartObjects collection of a Worksheet, and the equivalence Index=ZOrder was also verified.

PS2: One may ask if this is typical of (or even guaranteed for) any collection. In [Excel VBA: non sequential numbering of ZOrderPosition in Shapes collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152315/excel-vba-non-sequential-numbering-of-zorderposition-in-shapes-collection) I reported a case where, not only this is not true, but Index and ZOrderPosition are not even permutations (note that it was the Shapes collection of the Shape associated with a ChartObject, a case different from that mentioned above).

**Edit**: See Edit in [Excel VBA: How to obtain a reference to a Shape from the ChartObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146154/excel-vba-how-to-obtain-a-reference-to-a-shape-from-the-chartobject).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule "ZOrderPosition = index" for the shapes of an excel sheet is ** **NOT** ** true if you make a group of shapes. For example if you have the shapes "A","B","C","D,"E","F" in Zorder 1 to 6 and then you group shapes "B", "C", "D" together, you will break the "ZOrderPosition = index" rule for the shapes "E" and "F". If you list the shapes(i) you will get the following:

```
index  ZOrder  Name 
 1       1      "A"        
 2       2      "Group 1"   
 3      *6*     "E"        
 4      *7*     "F"
```

Here the code for getting the previous info:

```
Sub DebugListInfoOfShapes()
    Dim i As Long
    Debug.Print "Index   ZOrder   Name"
    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count
        Debug.Print i & "         " _
                      & ActiveSheet.Shapes(i).ZOrderPosition _
                      & "      " _
                      & ActiveSheet.Shapes(i).Name
    Next i
End Sub
```

Hoping this clarify you question!

Regards, Andres

PD: If you want to see shapes "B", "C", "D" you have to loop inside the group using for example: `ActiveSheet.Shapes(2).GroupItems(i)` for the case above.

Comment: Good point. Now, is this the only case where a difference is expected?

Comment: I have been exploring a lot about groups and shapes in excel lately, and I cannot imagine other case. I read somewhere that pictures or some OLE objects has one object inside other that can make trouble if you ungroup them, but was not my case so I didn't pay to much attention and not experimenting with that, either. If the last is true, it could be an effect on the ZOrderPosition if you use an OLE or Picture Object... Have to check...