# Iterating through ALL charts in an Excel worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

The following code works fine for 9 of 11 Charts. Two charts of the same worksheet are not affected. Why is that so ?

```
Sub resizeAllCharts()
    Dim myChartObj As ChartObject
    For Each myChartObj In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        With myChartObj
            .Height = 350
            .Width = 600
        End With
    Next myChartObj
End Sub
```

I also tried to access the chartobjects through indices and their Names:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(i)
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart " & i)
```

but this approach always resulted in exceptions. It seems that the charts in an Excel worksheet are not consecutive.

Comment: are all those charts on the active sheet? That sheet must be huge to fit 11 charts of that size... What does a `? Debug.Print ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count` in the Immediate Window returns?

Comment: yes, they are in the same active sheet. The change apply, but not for all. Two charts are always left unchanged

Comment: ?ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count
 11

Comment: can you add `Debug.Print myChartObj.Name` after the `End With` and before `Next ` ? Check your immediate window again and see if all the charts are being iterated

Comment: I got this:Chart 4
Chart 5
Chart 6
Chart 7
Chart 8
Chart 1
Diagramm 34
Chart 1

Comment: this is really odd. But answers the question why I couldn't iterate using charts name ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart " & i)

Comment: is that 8 out of 11 then? 3 seem to be skipped then... hm

Comment: can you by an chance upload your workbook to a free hosting site? It's really hard to tell what is wrong without actually seeing all the charts and code

Comment: It's for my work, so I'm not allow to share the excelsheet. I'm sorry

Comment: Ok, do this in immediate window `? ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Name` and keep replacing `(1)` with higher numbers. See if you can access all charts this way

Comment: A few notes: 1) It is strange that you have repeated chart names (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153331/duplicated-excel-chart-has-the-same-name-name-as-the-original-instead-of-increm)), 2) You said that the code works for 9 charts, but only 8 seem to be traversed by the loop. 3) Do you have grouped charts? [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146154/excel-vba-how-to-obtain-a-reference-to-a-shape-from-the-chartobject) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19159093/excel-vba-index-zorderposition-in-a-shapes-collection) *might* be useful.